# Is Customizing UIImagePickerController not allowed by Apple?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, addsubview

Friends, 
I would like to add a subview in UIImagePickerViewController, which allow user to select picture resolution so that i will resize it accordingly. 
I managed to do this.

Will my application get any problem in getting approved by Apple if we add subview to UIImagePickerController?

Please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using public API (which you seem to do) and you're not in any major violation of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines you're likely fine.